# Convert ADSL wireless router to AP, not able to connect to internet wirelessly

Tags: networking, router, wireless-router, wireless-access-point, adsl-router

I have a [Zyxel P-660HW-T1 v3 ADSL2+ Wireless Router](http://www.zyxel.com/uk/en/products_services/p_660hw_series.shtml?t=p). I have a PPPoE broadband connection. There is a CPE on the rooftop. An RJ45 cable comes down from the CPE to my house. I need to have wireless connection to my  smartphone and laptop.

To achieve this, I converted the Router to an AP. Wired connection works fine. But wireless doesn't work. I can connect to the AP but not to internet.

The IP address to get to the configuration page of CPE is 192.168.0.254

Steps followed to convert the Router to AP:

1. Disable DHCP
2. Disable NAT
3. Set IP address of ADSL router to 192.168.0.1 (default was 192.168.1.1)
4. Set Connection type to PPPoE. Enter username & pass. Leave all other values to their default ones.
5. Set SSID and security for wireless.
6. Reboot router
7. Connect RJ45 cable from computer to a LAN port in router and the CPE RJ45 cable to another LAN port in router.

Below is the CPE info page
[image]

Below are images of setup pages in the Zyxel router.

[image]

The drop-down options in **DHCP** were

1. Server
2. None
3. Relay

[image]

[image]

[image]

The drop-down options in **Modulation** were

1. ADSL G.dmt
2. ADSL2
3. ADSL2+
4. ADSL2 AnnexM
5. ADSL2+ AnnexM
6. Multi Mode
7. READSL2 Mode
8. ANSI T1.413
9. ADSL G.lite

The drop-down options in **Mode** were

1. Routing
2. Bridge

The drop-down options in **Encapsulation** for **Routing** were

1. PPPoA
2. RFC 1483
3. ENET NCAP
4. PPPoE

The drop-down options in **Encapsulation** for **Bridge** were

1. PPPoA
2. RFC 1483

The drop-down options in **Multiplexing** were

1. VC
2. LLC

**Update:** From the behavior of the router, it seems it is working like an unmanaged switch. It is actually not using the PPPoE login credentials at all. If I connect my desktop and laptop to it wired, I have to dial in (use the ISP login credentials) one of the machines to connect to the internet. And as it is PPPoE, I then cannot dial in the other machine to connect to internet....exactly like an unmanaged switch.

Comment: *"But wireless doesn't work. I can connect to the AP but not to internet."* -- Can you ping the wired PC from a wireless device?

Comment: @sawdust Yes, I can ping my Desktop (wired) from Laptop (wireless) and vice versa.